# Make svn diff output changed function names only

Tags: svn

How can i find out which function is changed from svn diff?

I just want to know function name in which code changes are made. 
In git, this is available as git diff --function-context.

Is there anything similar available for svn also?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

SVN diff has a option can show function name in the result, but not just function name.

```
-x [--extensions] ARG    : Specify differencing options for external diff or
                           internal diff or blame. Default: '-u'. Options are
                           separated by spaces. Internal diff and blame take:
                             -u, --unified: Show 3 lines of unified context
                             -b, --ignore-space-change: Ignore changes in
                               amount of white space
                             -w, --ignore-all-space: Ignore all white space
                             --igno`enter code here`re-eol-style: Ignore changes in EOL style
                             -U ARG, --context ARG: Show ARG lines of context
                             -p, --show-c-function: Show C function name
```

the changed line information is like this:

```
@@ -145,10 +145,6 @@ void UserOrder::getDBHandle() throw (CException)
     int index = SPEC_INDEX(gPtrDbPool, m_Params["Fbuy_uid"]);

     m_ptrUserTransOrderDBBuy = SPEC_SQL(gPtrDbPool, index);
-
-    index = SPEC_INDEX(gPtrDbPool, m_Params["Fsale_uid"]);
-
-    m_ptrUserTransOrderDBSale = SPEC_SQL(gPtrDbPool, index);
```

so, you can get the changed function names by a script.

Comment: Yeah, be sure to double check the output to see how accurate it is. I get the sense that SVN doesn't do a great job parsing C syntax